# CSS displaying trouble

Tags: html, css

Got the following css code:

```
#text input {
width: 200px;
}

#contact-form input[type=text], #contact-form input[type=file], #contact-form select {
width: 280px;
height: 30px;
}
```

and the HTML ...

```
<form id="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
...
<div id="text">
    <input type="text" name="x">
    <input type="text" name="y">

</div>
...
</form>
```

I want the two fields, named x and y to take the width from `#text input` css block, but at least in Chrome, the width from `#contact-form input` is used.

PS: forms are dynamically created with JS and the style of the element looks like this: `firstInput.style = "clear:none; margin:2px; width:200px";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few solution:

1.

```
#text input {
width: 200px !important; 
}
```

2.

```
#contact-form #text input {
width: 200px; 
}
```

3.change

```
#text input {
width: 200px;
}

#contact-form input[type=text], #contact-form input[type=file], #contact-form select {
width: 280px;
height: 30px;
}
```

to

```
#contact-form input[type=text], #contact-form input[type=file], #contact-form select {
width: 280px;
height: 30px;
}

#text input {
width: 200px;
}
```

it depends of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
#text input {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

OR

```
#contact-form  #text input[type='text']{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien can you elaborate?

Comment: You should avoid `!important` by writing specific selectors, using important instead will end up with more and more importants to override other importants...